# How to use css to show a border image?

Tags: wordpress, css

This code displays the border image only in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but not in IE 9 or 10. What changes needs to be made in the CSS and this code used in WordPress? Is there a plugin I can use to achieve this?

```
.Offset1 {
    width:525px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left:8px;
    border-style:double;
    border-width:30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-image:url("<?php echo  $vtheme_options['logo']; ?>") 30 30 30 30 stretch stretch; 
    -webkit-border-image:url("<?php echo  $vtheme_options['logo']; ?>") 30 30 30 30 stretch stretch; 
    -o-border-image: url("<?php echo  $vtheme_options['logo']; ?>")30 30 30 30 stretch stretch;
    border-image:url("<?php echo  $vtheme_options['logo']; ?>") 30 30 30 30 stretch stretch; 
    behavior:url(PIE.htc);
    position: relative; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .Offset1{ width:222px;
        margin-left:3px;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: where do you have a background image there ? or do you mean `border-image`? `border-image` is not supported for IE 9 and below. for IE 10 it probably will work with `-ms-border-image`

Comment: this is already .offset1

Comment: @t.niese: hello i have attached screen shot and background image.reply

Comment: @sumitdafhich: i just checked the ms specs and they tell that `border-iamge` is not supported in ie http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @t.niese:how to change in css supporting iE.this code work in iE4 and IE5 but not in IE9 and IE10

Comment: @sumitdafhich: the `border-image` is created in IE via the `behavior:url(PIE.htc)`  which is not supported in IE 10 anymore (for IE 9 you probably need to update PIE). so you need to look for another solution. e.g. `modernizr` to detect if `border-image` is supported and if not. display an alternative.

Comment: @t.niese:please change in code and after send . i have change in code border-image to modernizr but no change .

Comment: @t.niese:please reply

Comment: this code is run in IE8

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the property `border-image` is not supported by internet explorer. See this [1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image_button) little example code. Try it with different browsers, all work except internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because [Internet Explorer doesn't support border-image, at all](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image), and [PIE's support is very specific and limited](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-image), not to mention not supported at all in IE10.

In other words, you have to have very specific code, per PIE's documentation, to get it working in IE9 and below, and **you're not going to get it working at all in IE 10**.

I highly recommend just having a fallback for Internet Explorer and being done with it.

Comment: :hello please reply some example code support in IE9 and IE10.

Comment: @sumitdadhich - You're not going to *get* support for IE10. That's my point, and you're going to have to play with your code, based on the documentation that I linked for you, to get IE9 working properly.

Comment: @Shauna That sounded like a 'IE pissed off' developer answer.

Comment: @MilchePatern - How so? The PIE people don't even support border-image for IE10 (from the link "PIE adds support for the border-image property to IE 6-9"), and IE9's support is finicky, at best, for border-image with PIE's support. How can I provide code to make it work when there is none? (Of course, if you know of a way to make border-image work in IE9 and 10, then by all means, provide an answer here.)

Comment: @Shauna Sorry, this is not what i meant. Reading your answer sounded like me telling a colleague that **no, it wont work** thrust me, **it won't work**. Nothing relevant to this question, just situational to 'cross-browser' development ( with a smile ).

Comment: @Shauna:please reply. how to use code in IE9 and IE10. any plugin for wordpress so please send link

Comment: @MilchePatern:please reply. how to use code in IE9 and IE10. any plugin for wordpress so please send link